# find all solutions of $a^b=b^{a-3}$ over integers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

find all solutions of $a^b=b^{a-3}$ over integers.

I used the method of taking $\gcd(a,b)=d$ and simplifying the equation(this method is usually useful in this kind of questions a similar question in IMO is proved in this way.).I also tried the method of solving with factorization in that method we can prove if $a>b$ then $a \mid b$ but non of them worked.

Comment: With the possible exception of $(a,b) = (3,0)$ (which contains a degenerate $0^0$ term), unique factorization tells us that $a$ and $b$ must be powers of the same integer (i.e. $a = d^r$ and $b = d^s$ for some integers $d,r,s$, and unless $|d|=1$ we must have $r,s \ge 0$).  Have you tried this approach?

Comment: @ErickWong not exactly but I use the result that if $a>b$ we have $ b \mid a$ will it give sth more?

Comment: Letting the $\gcd$ be $d$ usually only helps if you have gcd in the original expression. I am pretty sure that there is a different and better approach than introducing $\gcd$ which can sometimes get ugly with powers. I will write a solution once I find a satisfactory solution.

Comment: @ErickWong why should $a$ and $b$ be powers of the same integer? Shouldn't they simply have same primes in their factorization, but the powers on the primes don't have to be proportional?

Comment: @Ivan They do have to be proportional, unless one of the two exponents is $0$ in the equation, which I took some care to rule out.

Comment: @NairitSarkar It also helps with power towers because $gcd(a',b')=1$ can easily simplify it for example in this case we get $a'=1$ so $a=d$ for seeing the usage see IMO1997 problem 5:https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1238p3845

Comment: @TahaAkbari Sorry. I didn't think about the problem that way.

Comment: Are you truly solving over integers or just over naturals?

Comment: @WillFisher  I saw the book again it is over naturals but solving over integers also gives finitive solutions so I won't edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $b=0$ leads to $a^0=0^{a-3}$ with only solution $a=3$.
- $b=1$ leads to $a=1$
- $b=-1$ leads to $\frac 1a=(-1)^{a-3}=\pm1$, but only $a=1$ works.

In all other cases, $b$ is divisible by at least one prime.
Also, we may assume $a\ne 3$ (because $a=3$ leads to $b=0$ again).

Let $p$ be a prime dividing $b$ and occuring in $b$ to the $k$th power (i.e., $p^k\mid b$, $p^{k+1}\nmid b$) with $k\ge 1$.
Then $p$ occurs in $b^{a-3}$ to the $(a-3)k$th power, hence in $a$ to the $\frac{(a-3)k}{b}$th power. In particular, $p\mid a$.
For $p\ne 3$, the pact that $\frac{(a-3)k}{b}$ is an integer and $\gcd(a-3,p)=1$ implies that $p^k\mid k$, which is absurd.
We conclude that $b$ is $\pm$ a power of $3$, $b=\pm3^k$, in particular, $b$ is odd.

On the other hand, if $q$ is a prime dividing $a$, we similarly find that $q\mid b$, hence $q=3$.
Then $3$ occurs in $a-3$ at most to first power. As $\frac{(a-3)k}{3^k}$ must still be an integer, $3^{k-1}\mid k$, we conclude $k=1$, so $b=\pm3$. So $a^3=3^{a-3}$, and with $a=3^m$, 
$ 3^{3m}=3^{3^m-3}$, $m=2$, $a=9$.

$$ (a,b)=(3,0), (1,1), (1,-1), (9,3).$$

Comment: I don't think a=3,b=0 is solution since it's leading to $0^0$

Comment: @EugenCovaci $0^0=1$

Comment: @WillFisher I think $0^0$ is undefined.Isn't it?Because $a^0=1$ where $a$ is not  $0$ and $0^a=0$ where $a$ is not $0$.

Comment: @TahaAkbari I think it's a matter of convention. You could also want $0^0=\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x=1$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $p\mid a\Longleftrightarrow p\mid b$, so we can write the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$ as
$$\begin{array}{c}
a=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_m^{\alpha_m} \\
b=p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2}\dots p_m^{\beta_m}
\end{array}$$
With this we see that $a$ and $b$ are solutions if and only if $\alpha_i b=\beta_i(a-3)$ for all $1\le i\le m$. This gives that
$$\frac{b}{\gcd(b,a-3)}\mid \beta_i$$
However this requires $b\le \beta_i\gcd(b,a-3)$. If $3\nmid a$ then $\gcd(b,a-3)=1$ and this clearly does not hold if $b\neq 1$. If $b=1$ then the pair $a=1,b=1$ works. If $3\mid a$ then $\gcd(b,a-3)=3$ and $b\le 3\beta_i$, however this clearly doesn't hold if $b$ has more than two distinct prime factors, so in this case $b=3^{\beta}$. However we still must have $3^{\beta}\le 3\beta$ which restricts $\beta$ to $1$. So $b=3$ at which point we see $a=9$ satisfies $a^3=3^{a-3}$. So if $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ then the solution pairs $(a,b)$ are $(1,1)$ and $(9,3)$.
Extending this to all integers shouldn't be hard by consider different combinations of when $a$ and $b$ are positive and negative. Simply check that both sides are integers or non-integers (for example one side can't be raised to a positive exponent and the other side a negative one). If they are both non-integers take the reciprocals of both sides and apply the same argument as above for when $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$.